# citep and citet not working even when using natbib package

Tags: latex, biblatex

I am writing a document in latex and I have a big .bib file and a large number of citations.
I want to have citations in the form [Author, year] format and am using the package *natbib*, but can't get **citep** or **citet** working, though plain cite is working fine. The error I get is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 lets cite \citet{cayton05}
```

I am using **Ubuntu texlive** package and use `\input{<file>}` latex command to input the chapters to the main .tex file.

What's surprising is that instead of using `\input{<file>}` if I just have text in the main .tex file then all the cite commands are working.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

The working version is like this:

```
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage[square,sort]{natbib}
%% lot of other packages and formatting %%

\begin{document}

\chapter{Testing citations}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item this is the first citation \cite{belkin02}.
  \item this is the second citation \citep{belkin02}.
  \item this is the third citation \cite{shlens03}.
\end{enumerate}



\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{testnb.bib}
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

In the real .tex file, I input the chapter text from another .tex file, and `citep` and `citet` won't work in that giving the aforesaid error, though plain `cite` will work fine.

I forgot to mention earlier I was using plain numbered bibliography style and everything was working, so there is no error in the input .tex files.

Comment: Just in case you arent aware, there is a more focussed Q&A site for Tex / latex - http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 19):

If `\citep` and `\citet` do not work, then you probably did not load `natbib`.

From a document I currently work on:

```
 \usepackage[authoryear,round,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
```

You may want different options -- see the [handy reference sheet for natbib](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php) for details.

Comment: Can you post a small self-contained example which fails to illustrate the issue?

Comment: I have loaded the natbib package like this: \usepackage[square,sort]{natbib}. I copied the same .tex and .bib file to a different directory and wrote some citations (citep and citet) in the .tex file itself (instead of using \input{}), and they are working fine. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Never mind ... the problem fixed itself. I never got to know what was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You should only include `\usepackage[square,sort]{natbib}`.

It will work after deleting `\usepackage{cite}`.